# Linking errors while building VTK

Tags: itk

I am trying to build ITKapps. I am using ITK 4.7., ITKapps 4.7. FLTK 1.1.3.

Some applications build ok, there is .exe and I can run them.

While building applications which use VTK always linking errors appears: cannot find vtkRendering.lib or vtkRenderingOpenGL.lib...

Problem is that I cant build VTK either. While building VTK there are also linking errors:
Error   3808    error LNK1104: cannot open file '......\bin\Debug\vtkRendering.lib'

I tried VTK 4.x and 5.x.. and not one version builds successfull.
 VTK 6.x builds ok but building ITKapps still have linking errors.(i don't think ITKapps works with VTK 6.x) so i must use version 4 or 5.

Maybe someone have idea what am I doing wrong or some sugestions?

Comment: Are you trying to build in debug, release or both?

Comment: In debug..i'm using cmake i forgot to say that.. and configuration goes well.. this happens when i go to ALL_BUILD in VS 2012

Comment: Are you targeting x86 or x64?  That would be the other thing I would check: make sure you are building for the correct architecture.

Comment: x86, i checked that already, that's ok... do you have something else maybe?

Comment: The obvious thing would be to check your library directory paths and make sure they are correct.  Do you know how to do this in VS?

Comment: I know how to. but since VTK 4.x and VTK 5.x doesn't build properly, most of the libraries are missing, they are not all in lib folder

Comment: Well you should definitely build VTK first, so I would concentrate on that particular error.  You checked that the "...\bin\Debug\vtkRendering.lib" path is correct?

Comment: I know. Yes i looked path, some libraries are there.  libraries are generated while building VTK right? and in that proceess (while building VTK) that error shows

Comment: If this error is still an issue - are you building the shared libraries in CMake before building VTK? If so I'd copy the debug dlls into the same folder as your exe.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error,  error LNK1104: cannot open file '......\bin\Debug\vtkRendering.lib' while trying to build VTK in VS 2012.  In Cmake I changed the VTK_RENDERING_BACKEND value from OpenGL to OpenGL2 and later the build succeeded in VS.